# WebView, cannot load html correctly

Tags: android, webview, httpurlconnection

I'm attempting to be more clever with loading a webpage into a WebView using HttpUrlConnection via AsyncTask. 
Previously i used WebView's `.loadurl()`

I've tested with `http://www.google.co.uk` and that seems to work fine.
I get the output below from the logs, unfortuantly i cannot determine what the actual issue is with loading this speicific page.

What i cannot figurue is why its talking about audio / video codex that are or are not supported. The web page has nothing todo with these.

When loading the HTML into the webview, i use:

`view.loadData(result, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);`

Sorry for such a blunt question.

```
08-17 15:59:00.610 26720-26720/com.admin.phonedivert D/INFO: <html>.....
08-17 15:59:00.616 26720-26720/com.admin.phonedivert I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is enabled.
08-17 15:59:00.652 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-17 15:59:00.664 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
08-17 15:59:00.665 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
08-17 15:59:00.668 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
08-17 15:59:00.674 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/Utils: could not parse long range '175-174'
08-17 15:59:00.675 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/dsd
08-17 15:59:00.675 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/alac
08-17 15:59:00.676 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
08-17 15:59:00.676 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
08-17 15:59:00.686 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
08-17 15:59:00.688 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
08-17 15:59:00.690 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
08-17 15:59:00.701 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
08-17 15:59:00.720 26720-26920/com.admin.phonedivert I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
08-17 15:59:00.758 26720-26720/com.admin.phonedivert W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 26720
08-17 15:59:00.771 26720-26720/com.admin.phonedivert I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: content_change is not defined", source: data:text/html; charset=UTF-8,<html>....
08-17 15:59:00.801 26720-26720/com.admin.phonedivert I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", source: data:text/html; charset=UTF-8,<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" /><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><title>Mobile App</title><link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><style type='text/css'>.button-back {        position: absolute;        z-index: 100;font-size: 49px;width: 45px;color: gray;margin-top: 2px;}.logo{ margin-left: 1px !important; }.mobile-menu {        display:none;        height:30px;        position: relative;        top: -40px;        right: -10px;}.mobile-menu div{        float:left;        width:120px;        height:40px;        background:white;} (1)
08-17 15:59:00.802 26720-26720/com.admin.phonedivert E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(99)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::AutofillDriver
08-17 15:59:02.262 26720-26720/com.admin.phonedivert I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7a4a838 time:33593818
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was down to insufficient HTML in the webpage.
Including `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` got this resolved. The Logcat errors are still unknown to relevance

Another problem that lead to this was using relative paths for style & javascript resources. I have an iframe that the webview points to. Since i was loading the HTML in direct to the view, the view had no idea where to look for the resources. I would of though using `loadDataWithBaseUrl()` would have solved this issue. However, this did not.

As a fix, i had to change all relative paths to static on my HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try to using this.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",result,"text/html", "UTF-8","");
```